# Permission denied when run Firebase pubsub scheduler function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-scheduler

I am totally stuck here. I created one pubsub scheduler function as below.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
exports.addTasksToQueueScheduler =  functions.pubsub
    .schedule('every 5 minutes')
    .onRun((context) => {
        console.log('This will be run every five minutes!');
  return null;
});
```

It is really simple function. I deploy it using

> firebase deploy --only functions

I can see my function is created the firebase function.
[image]

I logged into firebase cloud scheduler and there I can see the function. I click on "Run Now" buttons but I am getting Result= failed.

[image]

I added roles like **Cloud Functions Admin,
Cloud Scheduler Admin,
Cloud Tasks Admin,
Editor,
Owner,
Pub/Sub Admin,
Pub/Sub Publisher,
Cloud Run Invoker,
Storage Object Viewer** to default "App Engine default service account". This is really getting frustrating that they don't provide a proper documentation that which roles/permission required to run this. They just give all and you need to find out. A newbie can totally be lost it.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: You mention that you're getting a "permission denied" error, would you kindly post it here? They often come with an error code if they don't specify the precise role needed, if it's a Cloud Error, so that might make troubleshooting this a little smoother.

Comment: did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try deploying to the same region (this depends [which default resource location you've set](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions#before_you_begin)):

```
exports.addTasksToQueueScheduler = functions.region('europe-west1').pubsub
    .schedule('every 5 minutes')
    .onRun((context) => {
        console.log('This will be run every five minutes!');
        return null;
    });
```

Think it needs `roles/pubsub.subscriber`, so that the function can be invoked.

Comment: I applied region and assigned ```roles/pubsub.subscriber``` but it is still showing the same error.